# Hibernate query cache not refreshed with latest record of database

Tags: hibernate

I am having below issue with hibernate query cache.
My select query with condition return no result as the data in database doesn't match with the query condition. In this case hibernate save the query cache with identifier as blank. I insert the record into database that matches the query condition but the query cache always return null value instead of returning the latest record that I have added. Is there any way I could refresh the query cache with the updated record?

Here is the example - 
Select emp from Employee emp where name='TEST'
above query return no result from database so query cache has blank as identifier for above query key. Is there any way I could refresh the cache so that if record comes in Database for name='TEST', hibernate will return me the new record?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by evicting the cache region, this query belongs to:
`sessionFactory.getCache().evictQueryRegion([regionName])`

The method accepts a cache region name as parameter.

Or `cache.evictDefaultQueryRegion()` if your query is cached in the default query cache region (which is `org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache`)

If you plan only to invalidate cached result for the aforementioned query, I advice you to use a designated query cache for it (via `setCacheRegion()` method call)

Comment: I have a clusted environment and I am using JGroup for replicating cache. How will I evict the query cache in another node?

Comment: I have resolved this problem. I am using ehcache replication and we have replicateUpdatesViaCopy value was false for StandardQueryCache and UpdateTimestampsCache. I have changed that to true now query cache also replicating.